Equation for real/complex $\phi^4$ theory
On wikipedia (see this link), the Lagrangians of the $\phi^4$ equation for real AND complex scalar fields are given. One may derive the Klein-Gordon equation by inserting into the Euler-Lagrange-equations. This yields for the real scalar field
$$\partial_{\mu} \partial^{\mu} \varphi + m^2 \varphi + \frac{\lambda}{6} \varphi^3 = 0 \tag{1}$$
and for the complex scalar field
$$\partial_{\mu} \partial^{\mu} \phi + m^2 \phi + 2 \lambda |\phi|^2 \, \phi = 0 \tag{2}$$
(as well as the same equation with the replacement $\phi \longrightarrow \phi^{\ast}$). Interestingly, equation (2) does not become equation (1) when assuming that $\mathrm{Im} \phi = 0$.
1.) Is there any particular reason for taking these differing coefficients?
2.) The real part of $\phi$ satisfies the same equation (2) as the imaginary part of $\phi$. Assuming some uniqueness condition on the equation holds, one has $\mathrm{Re}\phi = \mathrm{Im} \phi$ for coinciding initial conditions. Am I missing something here or is solving the equation for $\mathrm{Re}\phi$ enough to determine $\phi$?

Yes. It seems that the $\lambda$'s are different. I wonder if the omission of the "!" in the complex case is deliberate? Of course the factorials are there to simplify the computation of symmetry factors, and the Feynman rules and combinatorics are different inthe two cases.


For what it is worth, the standard convention is to divide each term in the Lagrangian with its symmetry factor, e.g.
$${\cal L}~=~\mp \frac{1}{2}\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi-\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2-\sum_{n\geq 3}\frac{\lambda_n}{n!}\phi^n\qquad(\text{real scalar field})$$
$${\cal L}~=~ \mp\partial_{\mu}\phi^{\ast} \partial^{\mu}\phi-m^2 \phi^{\ast}\phi -\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{\lambda_{2n}}{(n!)^2}(\phi^{\ast}\phi)^n\qquad(\text{complex scalar field})$$
$${\cal L}~=~\mp \frac{1}{2}{\rm Tr}(\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi)-\frac{1}{2}m^2{\rm Tr}(\phi^2)-\sum_{n\geq 3}\frac{\lambda_n}{n}{\rm Tr}(\phi^n)\qquad(\text{$N\times N$ Hermitian matrix field})$$
with Minkowski sign convention $(\mp,\pm,\pm,\pm)$, respectively, cf. e.g. this & this Phys.SE post.

We leave it to the reader to work out what this means (i) for the corresponding Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations, and (ii) for the conversion of a complex scalar field into a pair of real scalar fields.


